# Ifstream inside a class

Tags: c++, ifstream

I don't understand what is going on. I have such code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("test.txt");
    if(!infile) return 1;
    infile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

It works alright. The file named "text.txt" doesn't exist. The application returns 1. But when I put the same code inside the class, it works otherwise. Here is the declaration:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Record
{
public:
    Record(char *filename);
public:
    ~Record(void);

private:
    ifstream infile;
}
```

And the constructor:

```
Record::Record(char *filename)
{
    infile.open(filename);

    if(!infile.is_open()) return;
}
```

It seems the method "is_open" doesn't work. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Saying something "doesn't work" isn't helpful. What did you expect to happen? What actually happened?

Comment: You're not putting the same code inside the cass... :-/

Comment: I expected the object will not created if a file doesn't exist. But object was created.

Answer (score 1):

It does work. What are you expecting? You're returning from the constructor, so the constructor will exit, the object will be created (with an invalid member) and execution will continue.

You can, instead, throw an exception to signal the invalid object:

```
Record::Record(char *filename)
{
    infile.open(filename);

    if(!infile.is_open()) 
        throw std::exception("file not found");
}
```

Comment: If the OP is modeling a class after istream, perhaps adding an is_open() member would be more appropriate?